# read any letter for my combobox

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have this simple query that populates a `ComboBox` with values:

```
 void fillCari()//fill Cari-med dropdown with values
    {
        try
        {

            string connectionString = "Data Source=LPMSW09000012JD\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Carimed_Inventory;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            con2.Open();
            string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Carimed";
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query, con2);

            SqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr2.Read())
            {
                string cari_des = dr2.GetString(dr2.GetOrdinal("Item_Description"));
                comboBox3.Items.Add(cari_des);
                comboBox3.Text.Trim();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

It does all that it needs to do which is when typing in a letter it starts to filter the drop down accordingly. What I want to next is to filter the dropdown box based on any value typed in. eg. If a word is say `"16 cat123"` usually the user would have to start off with typing the number `"16"` or the number `"1"` for it to show the results. Instead of this I would want if the user should start off by typing `"cat123"` then it still bring up the `"16 cat123"` which is the original item. How can I achieve this? Could this be done through that of the like operator within my `SELECT` query?

Comment: You should be disposing the SqlConnection, SqlCommand and SqlDataReader objects. either explicitly using `.Close()` or with `using (…` statements.

Comment: Yeah that was an over sight in my code, done now. @stuartd

Comment: If you have the option of using Entity Framework, it will make your life much easier.

Comment: I found a work around by using the guide of this user from [here](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/631196/combobox-with-suggest-ability-based-on-substring-s)
What was done by the author was that of overriding the default combobox setting in winforms. I just found a way to tie it into my code and got it up and running. Hopefully this is of help to someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

within the SELECT query you can ask it like that :

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query, con2);
string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Carimed WHERE Item_Description LIKE '%@TEXT%'";
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@TEXT", SqlDbType.NVARCHAR).Value = comboBox3.Text;
SqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
```

This should filter your query to select the words that contains the text typed. [This link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) may help you.